# Python comprehension list devuelve resultado diferente a for

Tags: python, bucles

Estoy realizando unas prácticas y no entiendo porque no obtengo el mismo resultado con una `comprehension list` que con un bucle `for`. El ejercicio lo que hace es ordenar los valores que están contenidos por un diccionario dentro de una lista , `list[dict[str,any]]`.

Es un reto de github de Asabeneh de 30-days-of-Python https://acortar.link/ph7mOr

Copio parte del output del for y de la comprehension list

```
data=[
    {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "capital": "Kabul",
        "languages": [
            "Pashto",
            "Uzbek",
            "Turkmen"
        ],
        "population": 27657145,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg",
        "currency": "Afghan afghani"
    },
    {
        "name": "Åland Islands",
        "capital": "Mariehamn",
        "languages": [
            "Swedish"
        ],
        "population": 28875,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
        "currency": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "name": "Albania",
        "capital": "Tirana",
        "languages": [
            "Albanian"
        ],
        "population": 2886026,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg",
        "currency": "Albanian lek"
    },
    {
        "name": "Algeria",
        "capital": "Algiers",
        "languages": [
            "Arabic"
        ],
        "population": 40400000,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/dza.svg",
        "currency": "Algerian dinar"
    },
    {
        "name": "American Samoa",
        "capital": "Pago Pago",
        "languages": [
            "English",
            "Samoan"
        ],
        "population": 57100,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/asm.svg",
        "currency": "United State Dollar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Andorra",
        "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
        "languages": [
            "Catalan"
        ],
        "population": 78014,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/and.svg",
        "currency": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "name": "Angola",
        "capital": "Luanda",
        "languages": [
            "Portuguese"
        ],
        "population": 25868000,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ago.svg",
        "currency": "Angolan kwanza"
    }

# For convencional:

def sorting_by_capital(data):
    arr_capital=[]
    for element in data:
        arr_capital.append(element["capital"])
    arr_capital.sort()
    
    return arr_capital

#output :

['', '', '', '', '', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Abuja', 'Accra', 'Adamstown', 'Addis Ababa', 'Algiers', 'Alofi',............

print(sorting_by_capital(data))


# Comprehension list:   ####   RESUELTO  ####

def sorting_by_capital(data):
    arr_capital = sorted([element["capital"] for element in data]]
  
    return arr_capital

print(sorting_by_capital(data))

output: OK
['', '', '', '', '', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Abuja', 'Accra', 'Adamstown', 'Addis Ababa', 'Algiers', 'Alofi',.............
```

Comment: Apostaría que `arr_capital.sort()` está mal indentado. Debería estar fuera del `for`.

Comment: deberia ser así, no tiene sentido ordenar siempre que repita el bucle.

Comment: Buenas @CandidMoe, el for convencional aparentenemente (son casi 2000 lineas) ordena correctamente. Pero la lista es la que la salida no logro que aplique el sort(). ¿A cuál te refieres?. Probé tanto arr.capital.sorted() como arr.capital.sort() , y no me aplica cambios de ninguno de los dos.

Comment: La comprensión de listas que usas es una atrocidad de tal magnitud que me niego a responder.

Comment: @Candid Moe, Atrocidad por mal aplicada, interpretada, estructurada....?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y explica la lógica de esa comprensión. A partir de eso podemos conversar.

Comment: No estaría mal que dejes la línea en que defines `data` para poder probar el código.

Comment: Buenas @Mateo, habia incluido la URL en la descripción, donde indico que es un reto de github, porque consideraba que eran demasiados datos para incluirlos. De todas formas tienes razón e incluí unas pocas líneas unicamente. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma correcta de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
lista = [ 
  { "nombre": "Afganistán", "capital": "Kabul", "idiomas": [ "Pashto", "Uzbeko", "turcomanos" ] }, 
  { "nombre": "Islas Åland", "capital": "Mariehamn", "idiomas": [ "Sueco" ] }, 
  { "nombre": "Albania", "capital": "Tirana", "idiomas": [ "Albanés" ] }, 
  { "nombre": "Argelia", "capital": "Argel", "idiomas": [ "Arábica" ] }, 
  { "nombre": "Samoa Americana", "capital": "Pago Pago", "idiomas": [ "Inglés", "samoano" ] }
] 

def sorting_by_capital( data ):
    arr_capital = sorted( [ element["capital"] for element in data ] )
    return arr_capital

print( sorting_by_capital( lista ) )
```

-> ['Argel', 'Kabul', 'Mariehamn', 'Pago Pago', 'Tirana']

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tiempo. Estoy empezando en esto y en ocasiones empiezo a crear un ovillo que es más grande que yo.

Comment: Maestro, un placer poder colaborar.

Answer (score 1):

Un list comprehension genera una lista. El ejemplo más simple es:

```
lista = [x for x in range(10)]
```

Que es equivalente a:

```
lista = []
for x in range(10):
    lista.append(x)
```

Nota que con list comprehension no se usa `append`. De hecho, si lo piensas un poco, no genera efectos secundarios. Cosa que tu código, sí hace. Ahí hay un error.

Además no guardas la lista en ninguna parte y como si fuera poco, no devuelves esa lista, devuelves `arr_capital`.

Por último la parte más rara del programa, no hay necesidad de usar 2 `if`s cuando en el código sin list comprehension no usa ni uno.

---

Corregido:

```
def sorting_by_capital(data):
# ---------------------
    arr_capital = [element["capital"] for element in data]
# ---------------------
    arr_capital.sorted()
    return arr_capital
```

Teniendo en cuenta el ejemplo que di al comienzo, nota que para pasar de la forma *convencional*, solo se hace en la sección delimitada:

```
def sorting_by_capital(data):
# ---------------------
    arr_capital = []
    for element in data:
        arr_capital.append(element["capital"])
# ---------------------
    arr_capital.sort()  
    return arr_capital
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta y sobre todo por el tiempo y la explicación que ,e has dado. Cierto es que no tenía ni pies ni cabeza la lista. Hay en ejemplos que veo que incluyen métodos o condicionales dentro de las listas y en algunos ejemplos los veo al comienzo y en otros detrás, estoy muy verde en esto todavía. Muchas gracias.